# What does a blue circle on the "Run" button in Matlab mean?

Tags: matlab

Title pretty much says it all.  I am running R2015a, and got this to appear in my editor.  There is a small blue circle appearing on the "Run" button.  I've never seen this before, and can't find any documentation on the mathworks website that explains it's meaning.

What does this blue circle with 3 dots mean?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When your .m file contains a function, not just a script, MATLAB lets you configure the "run" options.  The normal thing would be to thrown an error  because "Not enough input arguments", as you are trying to run a function without giving any.

However, if you click in the small arrow below "run", you can type some default arguments to pass to the function, when the function is run by clicking the green play. That way, it won't throw an error.  The blue dots mean that someone has written some default argument and MATLAB is telling you it will run the function with them.

Example:

```
function res= add(in1,in2)

res=in1+in2

end
```

Default parameters and ans:

[image]

If you try to run this code without having added the default parameters it will give an error.

Comment: Very interesting. So why doesn't it appear on each function-.m file that I open? Actually, I saw this sign only when my .m file (both script and function) has 'space' at the end of the name, e.g. 'main .m', so that it could not be executed.

Comment: @Adiel my guess is that what you mention is unexpected behavior. In MATLAB function names should not contain spaces, and if they do unexpected behavior happens.

Comment: It's probably a sort of automatic alternative suggest of MATLAB for run the unrunnable code... (In the case of space at the end of the file name, it's useless). But on which kind of function does it appear?

Comment: @AnderBiguri Sure spaces should not be there, It was my typo. But MATLAB gave this blue circle and tried to run the script without the space in the name, which didn't work, of course. Anyway, I didn't saw it in any function file, as you wrote.

Comment: @Adiel I don't want to hypothesize about how the undefined behaviour of the thing works, as I will probably fail. Still, this is what the blue circle is *supposed to do*

Comment: @AnderBiguri Suppose to do what? You see it always when you open a function .m file?

Comment: @Adiel no,no, its supposed to do what I descrived in the answer. In my case, I've never experienced any different behaviour.

Comment: Oh, Ok. Now I understood... Thanks.